# Continuity of function mapping $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ to $\mathcal{P}(X)$

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Given a topological space $Y$, let $\mathcal{P}(Y)$ be the set of all probability measures on $Y$, endowed with the weak* topology.

Let $X$ be a topological space (for convenience, it might be Polish or compact) and let $f\colon \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X)) \to \mathcal{P}(X)$ be defined by
$$ f(\mu)(E)=\int \nu(E) \mu(d\nu).$$
I can prove that each $f(\mu)$ is well-defined.

Is $f$ continuous?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Moreover, if $X$ is a metric space, then your map is Lipschitz with respect to the corresponding transportation metrics.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like mine was an easy question, and hence off-topic for this forum. Sorry for that. Since I could not (and still cannot) find an answer by myself, may I ask you some references (papers or textbooks) that might help me?

Comment: Use the fact that any continuous function $f$ on $X$ determines a continuous function $F(\mu)=\langle f,\mu\rangle$ on $\mathcal P(X)$.